# If hereditary superheroes were appearing, would muggles try to exterminate or profit off of them?

Tags: economy, super-powers

This question is based on the premise of the X-Men franchise, where superheroes that pass the potential for powers through heredity are used as a metaphor for persecuted minorities. I find this metaphor is self-contradictory because in real life the differences because skin-tone is cosmetic whereas super-villains potentially constitute an existential threat to the human race.

While I can understand trying to exterminate/brainwash/cure/rehabilitate super-villains, the vast majority of super powered individuals have human emotions and conscience. While they might cause accidental harm due to inexperience, they could potentially profit from their super powers.

Forget military applications, someone with [ice powers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iceman_(comics)) could open a year-round ski resort in the Bahamas! Even seemingly useless superpowers [could be exploited](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HeartIsAnAwesomePower) with enough creativity. To say nothing of how useful are mundane powers that make you equal to Einstein or an Olympic athlete.

Are muggles more likely to try exterminating all super people or more likely to exploit them?

Comment: Capitalism is about making profit. It totally depends on whether you can make more money by exploiting the abilities or by exploiting the fear of the unknown.

Comment: Oh, this just blew my mind: There are Muggles in this, too? So Harry Potter magic _and_ X-men superheroes?

Comment: No, "muggle" as a term has branched beyond the Potterverse. It simply means a normal, everyday human being with no special powers. In some contexts, it means any person without understanding of a group - for instance, live action roleplayers often call non-players muggles.

Comment: I never seen the term muggle used outside the Potterverse. But it's not hard to understand what he means.

Comment: I've seen stories with both ideas behind them. Ultimately, this is your story to tell.

Comment: Yes. Muggles would certainly try to exterminate or exploit them.

Oh, what's more likely? Well, what's the theme of your story?

Comment: What happened to good old vivisection?

Comment: Apparently, "muggle" is English English; the equivalent American term is "no-maj".

Comment: Okay I had to google muggle.  Did you mean someone who is not magical, someone who is outside this question, outside your canon, or am I not getting the reference.  I'm sorry I never saw the Harry Potter movies.  Maybe http://scifi.stackexchange.com/ would have a more educated answer?

Comment: I don't see why this question is so much more broad than most other world-building questions. The universe is well defined (X men universe basically), the question is pretty broad, but MANY questions we get into on world-building are, so this should not be closed.

Comment: **BOTH** The determining factor will likely be on an individual level, based whether or not they go against the existing status quo. Ski resorts are very independent and a new operator will not cause too much trouble. Someone who can mass / area of effect heal, someone who can produce infinity energy, or someone who is strong AND uses that power to overthrow the system will be purged. People already have power to do harm and disrupt already.  Those actively targeted NOW are people who go against the current system.  I don't see mass extermination happening unless most fall on the wrong side.

Comment: You lost my interest when you stooped to the term "Muggle".

Comment: "Are muggles more likely to try exterminating all super people or more likely to exploit them?"  This kind of question is problematic because either answer could be valid.  So this basically comes down to picking one or the other and then justifying it.  But you pretty well indicate which you prefer.  What don't you know?  What do you need answered?  This feels more like, "I had this great idea--don't you agree it's great?"  I don't understand what you don't know yet.

Answer (score 2):

In this context a super is no different from any other individual with gifts - for example a gifted singer.  Do I

1. Become her agent, maximize her potential and profit both of us?
2. Become her agent and ultimately rip her off?
3. Be her groupie and hope some glory rubs off on me?
4. Become her partner and form a band, because my bongo stylings are icing on her vocal cake.
5. Sabotage her because she is a threat to my own singingly endeavors?
6. Encourage her in a distant, avuncular way.  Nod and smile

All the regular stuff with interhuman interactions.  I cannot think of the agent angle having been done as regards supers.